# Is it possible to reboot a OS (linux) that is running within a Docker container? (to restart the GPU)

Tags: linux, cuda, docker, gpu

Usually when I install nvidia CUDA I have to reboot the system. Now I am installing it within a docker container and I get the following message:

```
# nvidia-smi -r -i 0

Error occurred while performing GPU Reset. GPU 0000:01:00.0 might be in 
an unstable state: Unknown Error

Please reboot your system.
```

So, how can I reboot the system?

I have tried executing "docker restart contained_id" but it did not solve the problem.

So, what is "docker restart" doing? And, is it possible to perform a regular reboot of the OS?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you install a GPU driver, you install a kernel module. As docker is not a virtual machine, that kernel is the host's one and shared across all containers. After installing the module, you need to restart the host machine.

Comment: Oh I see. Then my problem must be a different one, since the GPU driver is already running in the host, thus all relevant modules must be already loaded. Thanks for your insight.